# Correlation between non-independent time series data

Tags: time-series, correlation, seasonality, independence

I have count data on the number of individuals showing 5 different ventral colourations in a free-ranging populations of lizards across 12 years. As the data was collected in the same population, the relative frequencies are not independent. Each year we recorded a different total number of lizards (about 50).

We want to perform a time series analysis looking at possible correlations between the frequency of colour morphs taken two by two, but we don't know how to get rid of the necessary co-dependence introduced if we use relative frequencies, or of the different sample size between years if we use absolute frequencies. My dataset looks like this:

```
   Year Sex   orange  white  yellow   orange-white  yellow-orange  total
   2006   m     22       33     12      12                  8
   2007   m     12       11     34       4                  2 
   2008   m     45       12     43       5                  6
   2009   .    etc
   2010   .    
   2011   .    
   2012   
   2013   
   2014    
   2015 
   2016
   2017
   2006   f
   2007   f
    etc
```

Learning my first steps into time-series analysis i ended reading this (https://svds.com/avoiding-common-mistakes-with-time-series/) I thought to standadardize the count data for each morph across years, and de-trend by doing first-differences. Then, we could run simple correlations in R to examine potential correlation between pairs of colours. Would that be correct?

We would also like to evaluate the potential existenc of cycles and whether morph frequencies can be considered to be stable (or vary) across years.

P.D. We are mainly interested in orange-white-yellow relationship,  not that much in the two mixed colour morphs.